# How can I prove $a^2 +b^2 >2ab$ only with Natural numbers?

Tags: alternative-proof

I need to show $a^2 +b^2 > 2ab$ , but only with natural numbers, for that reason, I can't use negative numbers, the zero, or others non-natural numbers, e.g. I can't use the fact  $(a-b)^2 > 0$

Comment: If you can't use $(a-b)^2 > 0$, can you use $(b-a)^2 > 0$ instead?

Comment: Use AM-GM then.

Comment: Usually inequality axioms involve comparisons with 0. What kind of axioms do you suggest to use?

Comment: @Kaind And how would you prove AM-GM? I would start with this inequality, then work from there. So to me, using AM-GM here would be circular.

Comment: @Arthur Proof using induction on $n$ (no. of variables).

Comment: Also, obviously the inequality is false for $a=b$ (even if they aren't $0$). But then again, *no zero allowed*.

Comment: The question is ill posed. It is not true, for example, if $a=b$.

Comment: @Kaind And what's the base case? To me, it's this exact inequality (or maybe a single variable if you're feeling trivial, but I like starting at 2) . What's the induction step? To me, it's this exact inequality. So that makes it circular.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One of $a$ or $b$ is larger, so say $a<b.$   Then for some $c$, $b=a+c.$
Substitute this in to the left side:

$$a^2+b^2 = a^2 +(a+c)^2 = 2a^2+2ac+c^2 > 2a^2+2ac = 2a(a+c) = 2ab.$$

Comment: Doesn't the existence of $c$ require $0$? I think the OP must mention which framework they are working with - clearly it is something more primitive that Peano's axioms.

Comment: Is  the relation $a<b$ defined as an existence of $c$?

Comment: @Kaind  He said "natural numbers".  So I'm assuming Peano but just not allowed to use zero.  $b$ is some successor of some successor of ..... $a$.  $c$ is how many times you write "successor."